# Unexpected missing value from Wikidata query

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I'm using the [Wikidata query service](https://query.wikidata.org) to learn the SPARQL query language. I'm trying to get information on countries and their identifying information.

Here is a simple query which is intended to return a list of countries (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6256) along with their [ISO 3-letter codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P298):

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?iso
WHERE 
{
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256;   # wd:Q6256="country; wd:Q3624078="sovereign state"
           wdt:P298 ?iso.
}
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

I notice that at least one country is consistently missing from the results, Georgia, and I'm confused about why.

According to [its wikidata page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q230):

1. It is an instance of country (`wd:Q6256`)
2. It does have an ISO-3166 3-letter country code (`wdt:P298`)

I've tried various transformations of this query (e.g. don't include the ISO codes, use labels in different languages, etc) and I consistently get the same result: Georgia is missing.

However if I switch from (instance of a country `wd:Q6256`) to (instance of a sovereign state `wd:Q3624078`; a subclass of `wd:Q6256`), then Georgia *is* included in the results.

I am at a loss to explain this result; the entity in question should be an instance of *both* "country" and "sovereign state." And clearly it works for most of the other countries of the world, whose data is represented similarly in Wikidata, in that they're listed as instances of *both* country `wd:Q6256` and sovereign state `wd:Q3624078`.

Can anyone explain what aspect of the SPARQL language, or representation of the data in question, that I'm not understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim for instanceOf Sovereign State has a `PreferredRank`, so it's selected in preference to all the other claims which have a `NormalRank`. Also, SPARQL doesn't do inheritance by default unless you explicitly bake it into the query (because it can be expensive), so you don't automatically get Sovereign State just because it's a subclass of Country.

This will include Georgia

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?iso
WHERE 
{
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  ?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6256;   # wd:Q6256="country; wd:Q3624078="sovereign state"
           wdt:P298 ?iso.
}
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

but note that it includes deprecated claims as well. I cribbed it from this set of examples: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks

As mentioned by @horcrux in the comments, you can modify this to exclude deprecated claims by using a FILTER expression:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?iso
WHERE 
{
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  FILTER(?rank != wikibase:DeprecatedRank) . ?country p:P31 [ ps:P31 wd:Q6256 ; wikibase:rank ?rank ] ;
           wdt:P298 ?iso.
}
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

The results are the same in this case, but it's something worth thinking about when you're considering what kind of data you're looking for.

Comment: For excluding potential deprecated claims, one can use `FILTER(?rank != wikibase:DeprecatedRank) . ?country p:P31 [ ps:P31 wd:Q6256 ; wikibase:rank ?rank ] ;` instead of `?country p:P31/ps:P31 wd:Q6256;`

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Now that I look very closely at the individual entity pages, and know what to look for, I can see that [Georgia/Q230](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q230) has `PreferredRank` for instanceOf Sovereign State, whereas other countries (e.g. [Afghanistan/Q889](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q889)) have `NormalRank` for instanceOf Country and Sovereign State. This appears to be the source of the discrepancy, as you demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, it's well disguised. I should have mentioned to look for the tiny up/down arrows which indicate the rank.